# Disconnect from a wifi network programmatically in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-studio, wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow

```
 Disconnect from a wifi network programmatically in Marshmallow
```

Unable to a disconnect from a wifi network programmatically in marshmallow can not find any solution. If any one is having any solution will be huge help .Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    wm.disconnect();
```

Also set permissions to Change Wifi State in Manifest and also at Runtime for devices running Android 6.0

Inside **Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Check **permission at Runtime:**

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SmsOtpCheck.this, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE}, CODE);
```

After approving or rejecting permission:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CODE:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    //PERMISSION GRANTED
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not wants to turn off the wifi. i just wants to disconnect from particular network

Comment: changed `wm.setWifiEnabled()` to `wm.disconnect()`

Comment: given all the premissions at run time for marshmallow and used removNetwork(networkId) but its not working for marshmallow .

Comment: If it works, do **mark the answer correct and vote up. Thanks**

Comment: No it will not work because i want to disconnect to a particular network it wont disconnect . Thanks for the answer

Comment: At once, you can only connect to One wifi network. You don't have an option to select a particular wifi network and disconnect from it.

Comment: If by disconnect you mean, removing that wifi configuration from the saved wifi lists, then the question itself is wrong.\

Comment: I connected to a wifi network by passing SSID and Password through my code .but when i wants to disconnect or forget that network in marshmallow its not working

Comment: and also whenever i tried to connect to other network my app got stuck and i got this issue "Failed to chmod(/sdcard/appName): android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)"